# Dtrace problems with cs_cid in tcp probe

Tags: tcp, dtrace

I'm trying to analyse the TCP sliding window using DTrace. I have found the following blog post (https://blogs.oracle.com/amaguire/entry/dtrace_tcp_provider_and_tcp) which includes a dtrace script. Unfortunately, I always get the error

```
line 4: translator does not define conversion for member: cs_cid
```

I also checked the documentation for the tcp probe (https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/tcp+Provider) and cs_cid seems to be defined.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any advise would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that the script that you've found exploits OS-specific knowledge of Solaris and is therefore irrelevant to OS X.

Looking at [Solaris's documentation for the tcp provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/glhgu.html#glhmv) shows that, for `tcp:::send`, `args[1]` is of type `csinfo_t *` where

```
typedef struct csinfo {
    uintptr_t cs_addr;
    uint64_t cs_cid;
    pid_t cs_pid;
    zoneid_t cs_zoneid;
} csinfo_t;
```

This isn't a kernel data structure:  it exists solely for the benefit of DTrace consumers and is populated dynamically by a [translator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkylj.html#scrolltoc).  This allows the OS implementation to change without breaking scripts that have come to rely on the interface.  On a Solaris system, you'd find the definition of `csinfo_t` and its translator in `/usr/lib/dtrace/ip.d`.

Different vendors are free to implement providers as they see fit.  From what you've written, it seems that on OS X either `tcp:::send`'s `args[1]` is not a `csinfo_t *` or a `csinfo_t` doesn't contain a `cs_cid`.  Without any evidence that the OS X tcp provider mirrors Solaris's then I'd say it's fruitless to pursue the use of your script.

Note that a provider needn't necessarily be for end users.  If there's no public documentation for it then I'd have a look to see if there are any OS X utilities using it --- have a look for any files containing, e.g., the string "`tcp:::`".  Maybe there's already something there that does what you want.

Comment: it seems like cs_cid is not even available on mac os x. I used a combination of src ip, src port, dest ip, dest port as a substitute for cs_cid. I'm not sure if that's appropriate substitution but it worked for me.